# handle n+1 with hasManyThrough relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eager-loading

my product has relation called values which is like this:

```
public function values()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(VariantValue::class, VariantProductOption::class, 'product_id', 'product_option_id');
}
```

everything works fine but when i have a multiple products in a single pages n+1 problem happens:

```
select `variant_sku_values`.*, `variant_sku_product_options`.`product_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `variant_sku_values` inner join `variant_sku_product_options` on `variant_sku_product_options`.`id` = `variant_sku_values`.`product_option_id` where `variant_sku_product_options`.`product_id` = 61520 and `option_id` = 1
1.16ms
-----------------------------------------
arya-lion
select `variant_sku_values`.*, `variant_sku_product_options`.`product_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `variant_sku_values` inner join `variant_sku_product_options` on `variant_sku_product_options`.`id` = `variant_sku_values`.`product_option_id` where `variant_sku_product_options`.`product_id` = 81066 and `option_id` = 1
1.09ms
-----------------------------------------
arya-lion
select `variant_sku_values`.*, `variant_sku_product_options`.`product_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `variant_sku_values` inner join `variant_sku_product_options` on `variant_sku_product_options`.`id` = `variant_sku_values`.`product_option_id` where `variant_sku_product_options`.`product_id` = 81069 and `option_id` = 1
1.07ms
------------------------------------------
arya-lion
select `variant_sku_values`.*, `variant_sku_product_options`.`product_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `variant_sku_values` inner join `variant_sku_product_options` on `variant_sku_product_options`.`id` = `variant_sku_values`.`product_option_id` where `variant_sku_product_options`.`product_id` = 93662 and `option_id` = 1
1ms
-----------------------------------------
arya-lion
select `variant_sku_values`.*, `variant_sku_product_options`.`product_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `variant_sku_values` inner join `variant_sku_product_options` on `variant_sku_product_options`.`id` = `variant_sku_values`.`product_option_id` where `variant_sku_product_options`.`product_id` = 93724 and `option_id` = 1
```

i tried to eager load the **values** relation but this doesnt work.

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: How are you performing the `get()` for the `values`? That is the line which we need to provide an answer.

Comment: @Coola $product->values()->where('option_id',1)->get() like this

Comment: @KhangTran sure what do you want to know

Comment: Followup - How are you getting the `$product`?

Comment: @Coola $products = ProductModel::with(['values']); like this

Comment: What is the intermediate relationship for the "through"? I think you need to define that and add that to the `with` statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253207/discussion-between-arya-la-and-coola).

Answer (score 0):

You can use with for eager loading like this-

```
public function values()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(VariantValue::class, VariantProductOption::class, 'product_id', 'product_option_id')
                ->with('variantProductOption');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with help of @Coola i somehow find the solution by eagerloading the relation
like below:

```
Product::query()->with([
                'values' => ['value' => ['option']],
            ])
```